# Fundo preto imagem python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou usando o pdf2image para exportar as paginas de pdf e juntar em apenas um jpg, uma pagina em baixo da outra formando uma "tripa", porém o meu arquivo todo fica com o bg preto.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: UTF-8

import img2pdf
import os
import time
import sys
import tempfile
import webbrowser
import colorama
import PIL
import numpy as np
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

class ConvertPdf2Img():

@classmethod
def export(self, one_page = False):
    filename = os.path.join(sys.path[0] ,'pdfs', 'nt.pdf')
    save_dir = os.path.join(sys.path[0] ,'jpgs')
    list_jpg = []

    time.sleep(2)
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Iniciando exportacao PDF > JPEG..." + Style.RESET_ALL)

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory():
        images_from_path = convert_from_path(filename, 300)

        i = 0
        for page in images_from_path:
            i += 1

            print(Fore.RED + "Exportando pagina page-" + str(i) + ".jpg ..." + Style.RESET_ALL)

        save_filename = os.path.join(save_dir, 'page-' + str(i) + '.jpg')
        page.save(os.path.join(save_dir, save_filename), 'JPEG')

        list_jpg.append(save_filename)

    time.sleep(2)

    images = map(Image.open, list_jpg)
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    total_width = max(widths)
    total_height = sum(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, total_height))

    offset = 0
    for im in images:

        # center
        x = int((total_width - im.size[0])/2)

        new_im.paste(im, (x, offset))
        offset += im.size[1]

        new_im.save(os.path.join(save_dir, 'tripa.jpg'))

     if(one_page):
         for jpg in list_jpg:
             os.remove(jpg)

     print(Fore.GREEN + "JPEG finalizado ! Abrindo pasta com jpg(s) convertidos..." + Style.RESET_ALL)
     time.sleep(2)
     webbrowser.open('file:///' + save_dir)

 # chamando metodo
 me = ConvertPdf2Img()
 me.export(True)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O map tem de ser convertido numa lista.

```
images = list(map(Image.open, list_jpg))
```

Comment: dessa forma ele me retorna erro 'MemoryError'

Comment: se eu usar um pdf com 5 paginas por exemplo ele funciona, mas terei pdf com 18 por exemplo, ai ta estourando